# Disable / Catch Alt + F4 Key Combination C++

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, windows-10, mingw

I am writing a C++ Console App for Windows. I need to disable the ALT + F4 key combination that normally closes the window. How can this be done?

Comment: Since when does Alt+F4 close a console window?

Comment: @ssbssa it does

Comment: I see, apparently this changed in Win10. And [according to this](https://superuser.com/a/1572909) you can restore the old behavior.